# Full calendar weekly and monthly events with occurences

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I am really having a problem with implementing weekly and monthly event for my module. I have a module that can insert and edit a single event but I can't seem to find a way of how to make an event be weekly and monthly. I mean, i know that DOW property can make a single event be weekly but i want my weekly event to have an occurence/range.  I tried searching about this issue but I didn't find anything. My module is for a church event so a weekly or monthly event is really a must.

Can anyone give me a link regarding this issue? or a different calendar plugin instead? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you could have your data source simply keep returning the same event objects if it satisfies some condition and updating the week/month to the appropriate week/month with [lazy fetching](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/lazyFetching/)

Comment: fullCalendar doesn't support this kind of repetition natively unfortunately. So if you have in your database some kind of entry defining the pattern of repetition, then you can retrieve that, and write some logic on your server side which will create a series of individual events for each of the dates / times which match the repeating pattern, and also fall within the start / end dates requested by fullCalendar. It then just means for the purposes of displaying on the calendar they are individual events, but in your database you can store enough info to define the repetition when needed